# Multiple rules for one target

Tags: makefile

I have large project and it's compiled on-demand on several different machines with different OS'es.
One of targets has `foo.res` in it's dependencies. This resource file can be compiled using either one of 2 different rules:

First rule requires text file `foo.txt` to be present. This rule also requires some of the non-cross platform software to be installed in the system. This rule can not be used in-field by the our engineers, as it won't run under old MacOS.

Second rule uses pre-compiled resource file `foo.res` in resources directory and simply copies it to `build/`. Obviously, this is unwanted workaround, but i have no other choice.

I've tried to describe 2 rules in one Makefile, but i've got such error:

```
Makefile:78: warning: overriding recipe for target 'build/foo.res'
Makefile:75: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'build/foo.res'
```

Currently I use Makefile with one of the rules commented-out:

```
.PHONY: compile
build/app.bin: some_files... build/foo.res
    (Here is compiler call)

build/:
    -mkdir build/

.PHONY: clear
clear:
    -rm -rf ./build

... Lots of stuff here ...

# build/foo.res: res/foo.res | build/.
#     cp res/foo.res build/foo.res

build/foo.res: res/foo.txt | build/.
    some_app -o build/foo.res res/foo.txt
```

I deploy pre-compiled `res/foo.res` to some machines and then I swap commented rules, so regular `cp` is used. This works fine, until some changes are introduced to Makefile in some of commits. Then it blocks fast-forward update in git.

**How can I configure make to fire only one of the rules, based on matched dependencies?**

Comment: Well, since it's `res/foo.txt` -> `build/foo.res` -> someting needing `foo.res` a relatively obvious workaround would be to deploy precompilerd `foo.res` to `build/foo.res` instead of `res/foo.res`. That should make `make` happy as satisfying the prerequisite using a single rule (latter / not commented one in your case) without ever needing to try to build `build/foo.res` . `make` is not particularly smart or picky when it comes to determining in-/valid prerequisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with explicit rules.  An explicit rule tells make *THIS* is how you build this target.  You *can* create two different pattern rules that can build the same target.  A pattern rule says this is *one way* you can build that target.

So, change your makefile to:

```
build/%.res: res/%.res | build/.
        cp $< $@

build/%.res: res/%.txt | build/.
        some_app -o $@ $<
```

Comment: I should point out that this is GNU make-specific; you are using GNU make (as evidenced by the errors you quote) but you didn't tag it.